# Rotated elements collision / overlapping detection

Tags: javascript, jquery

need some help with detecting collision / overlap of 2 elements of which one is dynamically rotating.

I'm making a game where a user controls a sword which rotates and moves depending on mouse cursor position, the image used for that is 5 pixels wide and 130 long. Rotation possible over a full 360 degrees. I will have targets spawning across the page which the user needs to slash with his sword, so I need to detect when the image slices through one of the target divs. I can't seem to be able to get a working detection going because of the rotation of the image.

Is there anyone that can point me in the right direction / has a solution for detections such as these?

Example of what I have so far here, no proper detection yet

http://tinyurl.com/ovfhfwx

I started off with something like the following

```
var square = {x: 500, y: 500, width: 25, height: 25}
var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    var lightsaber = {
        x: getOffset( document.getElementById('lightsaber') ).left,
        y: getOffset( document.getElementById('lightsaber') ).top,
        width: $("#lightsaber").width(),
        height: $("#lightsaber").height()
     }

    if (lightsaber.x < square.x + square.width &&
       lightsaber.x + lightsaber.width > square.x &&
       lightsaber.y < square.y + square.height &&
       lightsaber.height + lightsaber.y > square.y) {
        console.log('collision');
       //clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
 }, 33);
```

This obviously didn't rotate the collision box and just worked as if it was always standing straight, I was hoping there would be some similar solution like this but where it does rotate the collision box.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some code directly in the question

Comment: I don't have any code relating to the collision yet since what I had wasn't taking any rotation into account and just comparing the offsets with the width and height. I'm looking for a direction to start in here, the link was just to show how the sword moves and what the targets like.

Comment: Well, you usually come here with at least a start... But well, here is a start : do some maths ! Calculate the coordinates of the 4 points of your objects with some `position()`, `Math.cos()`, `height()`, ... and see if any of them are within another object. Check this on the `mousemove` event

Comment: I added what I had before which did not account for rotations. I'll fiddle some more and see if I can wrap my head around it, additional pointers always welcome;